# Motherboard for photo processing

Tags: desktop

I'm looking for a desktop configuration. Primary use would be processing photographs in Lightroom and Photoshop (very basic). As far as I read in such use cases graphic card is far less important than fast memory, a fast CPU and a fast disk.

I was thinking about the following configuration:

- CPU: Intel Core i5-6600K BOX 3.5GHz, 6MB
- Memory: Patriot Viper 4 DDR4 DIMM 2x8GB 3000MHz
- SSD: ADATA 256GB SP600 SSD
- HD: WD 1TB 64MB SATA III
- DVD: LG GH24NSD1 BLACK RECORDER DVD SATA

EDIT:

Now, I am looking for motherboard for this configuration. It must:

- have graphic card built-in
- have a possibility to connect external graphic card in the future
- have 4 DIMMs slots
- seat a core i5-6600K
- have WiFi built-in
- have a space for CPU cooler, because the mentioned i5 doesn't have it's own cooler
- preferrably ATX
- budget ~130 USD

What motherboard would you recommend?

Comment: Your title suggests you need a motherboard recommendation, your first sentence suggests you don't know what CPU/GPU to purchase, and your last two questions suggest that you need a power supply and CPU cooler recommendation. I'm voting to close this question as unclear.

Comment: Your last questions are still asking multiple things; a moderator will close your question soon if you do not edit to ask **one single thing** with specific guidelines in mind - e.g. "5 PCIe slots and 3 SATA ports". Asking what stuff you should get might be better suited for [Reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/buildapc/)

Comment: You are basically looking for a mobo with 4 DIMMs, seats a core i5-6600K, has at least 3x SATAIII connections.  What size motherboard will your chassis take:  ATX? mATX? mini-ITX? micro-ATX? E-ATX?  What is your budget?  You need to expand on these things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend the [Z170A SLI PLUS](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B019EYYNP0). It costs about $135 on Amazon.com. I use this motherboard in a personal rig, and it performs well.

The reasons why I would recommend this motherboard are:

- It uses the z170 chipset, which is overclockable, and because it will allow you to overclock you unlocked i5 6600k.
- Supports DDR4-3000 RAM
- Has four DIMM slots
- Has room for large CPU coolers -- I'm using a [Thermaltake NiC C5](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00E1JA1PA) with this motherboard. The NiC C5 a large cooler but, it still allows me to use all four RAM slots.
- 6 SATA ports with RAID 0, 1, 5 and 10 Support
- Reinforced PCIe x16 Slots for large graphics cards
- Excellent Overclock-ability
- ATX Form Factor
- [Reasonable iGPU performance](http://www.guru3d.com/articles-pages/msi-z170a-sli-plus-review,19.html) (integrated GPU)